# A column Genre in movies data set have multiple categories in each row. How can I separate all the categories from each other?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

This is the code:

```
data[['Movies','Genre']
```

The output looks like this:

```
    Movies Genre
1    Xyz   Drama,Action
2    Abc   Horror,Thriller
3    Mnb   Action,Thriller
```

The desired output is:

```
    Movies Genre
1    Xyz   Drama
2    Xyz   Action
3    Abc   Horror
4    Abc   Thriller
5    Mnb   Action
6    Mnb   Thriller
```

And if I do: `data["Genre"]max()` it should give: `Action, Thriller`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to convert `Genre` from `str` to `list`; secondly, you transform each element of a list-like to a row using [`pandas.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

```py
>>> df["Genre"] = df["Genre"].str.split(",")
>>> df
  Movies               Genre
0    Xyz     [Drama, Action]
1    Abc  [Horror, Thriller]
2    Mnb  [Action, Thriller]
>>> df.explode("Genre")
  Movies     Genre
0    Xyz     Drama
0    Xyz    Action
1    Abc    Horror
1    Abc  Thriller
2    Mnb    Action
2    Mnb  Thriller
```

Comment: Also, `df["Genre"].max()` would return a single value, so I think `df["Genre"].mode()` should be used istead; it returns both *Thriller* and *Action* values.

Comment: if I do this and then I want to restore the previous version (per seen in question) what should I do?

Comment: @K.Patel, the easiest way is to create a separate variable. Assuming your original dataframe was stored as `df1`, you could create `df2 = df1.copy()`, and do all transformations with `df2` variable: `df2["Genre"] = df2["Genre"].str.split(","); df2 = df2.explode("Genre")`. Now you still can access you original dataframe with `df1`